# ¿ Cómo cambiar tipo de fuente si no es textView?

Tags: android, fuentes

Tengo una base de datos en un tipo `Fragment` y me gustaría cambiarle el tipo de letra y siempre he conseguido hacerlo porque era un `TextView` pero en esta ocasión, lo que me interesa es `texto` y `texto2` pero son tipo `String` y cuando pongo el siguiente código, me sale en rojo el "typeface":

**¿ Cómo lo hago?**

```
String font_path = "fonts/TitilliumWeb-BoldItalic.ttf";


Typeface TF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),font_path);

View2.setTypeface(TF);
View3.setTypeface(TF); //eso es
```

**Código**

`public class First_fragment extends Fragment {`

```
ListView lstCursos;
String recuperado;
public final static String CLAVE_EXTRA_PASAR2 = "true";

private ListView mylist;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab, container, false);
    //De este modo cambiamos el tema para cada uno de los layout
    getActivity().setTheme(R.style.Barra);

    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);



    Bundle recupera = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras ();
    if (recupera != null) {
        recuperado = recupera.getString ( "cod" );
    }

    Thread tr2 = new Thread () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final String resultado = enviarGET ( recuperado );
            getActivity().runOnUiThread ( new Runnable () {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ////////////////////////////////////////
                    cargarListView ( ArregloLista ( resultado ) );
                    ////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            } );
        }
    };
    tr2.start ();
    return v;
}

public String enviarGET(String id){

    URL url = null;
    String linea = "";
    int respuesta = 0;
    StringBuilder resul = null;

    try {
        //url = new URL ("http:xxxxxxxx"+id);
        url = new URL ("http://xxxxxxxx"+id);
        //Ahora enviamos el dato
        HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
        //Guardamos la respuesta en el entero, porque sera un uno o un cero
        //Esto es lo que devuelve la BD una vez hacemos la consulta
        respuesta = conection.getResponseCode ();
        //Inicializamos resul
        resul = new StringBuilder ();

        if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(in));

            while ((linea = reader.readLine ()) != null){
                resul.append (linea);
            }

        }
        return resul.toString (); // Esto debe ir aquí porque si lo pongo fuera del try devueleve NUllException y se crashea.

    } catch (Exception e) {


        Intent intencion = new Intent(getActivity(),SinInternet.class);
        intencion.putExtra(CLAVE_EXTRA_PASAR2, "true");
        startActivity(intencion);
        return null;

    }
   // return resul.toString ();
}

//Metodo que permite crear un arraylista para llena el listview
public ArrayList<String> ArregloLista(String response){
    ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String> ();
    try {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray (response);
        String texto = "";
        String texto2 = "";




        for(int i=0;i<json.length ();i++){

            //Cambiamos las fuentes


            texto = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("titulo");
            texto2 = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("descripcion");
            listado.add("\n" + texto + "\n\n" +texto2 + "\n");



        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return listado;
}

//Aquí es donde va TODA LA CHICHA
public void cargarListView(ArrayList<String> datos){
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);
    lstCursos = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById (R.id.listCursos);
    lstCursos.setAdapter (adaptador);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cambiar el tipo de letra a que? ¿A un `Fragment` entero? En un `Fragment` puede haber muchas mas cosas que solo texto

Comment: Mis entradas en la base de datos tienen 2 textos (título y descripcion) , lo he puesto al principio bandicoot, si no lo aclaro ahora, cambiar la fuente a  esos textos, a ``texto`` y ``texto2`` que en verdad, es lo único que se ve de dicho fragment.

Comment: String recuperado, es solo una variabhle que guarda texto, nunca se vera si no lo asignas a un textview, edittext, button, toolbar, etc

Comment: Tu texto aparece en un listView por lo que vas a tener que crearte un adaptador personalizado, en el que el texto que aparezca en el listView tenga la fuente que deseas.

Comment: Puedes hacer un cutomAdapter y crear un contenedor para tus items, colocando textviews y ahí si ya aplicar tus fuentes.

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente no puedes definir una fuente a una variable tipo String:

```
 String texto = "";
 String texto2 = "";
```

Se puede definir pero a la vista. La fuente debe encontrarse dentro del folder `/assets` ya que estas usando `getAssets()`, por ejemplo:

```
String font_path = "TitilliumWeb-BoldItalic.ttf";
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), font_path);

TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
title.setTypeface(font);
```